# JavaMail não envia email

Tags: email, jsp

Eu estava desenvolvendo uma pagina para envio de e-mail.
Enviava legal, porém mesmo não dando erro na página o mesmo não envia mais.
Segui esse tutorial [aqui](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_sending_email.htm). Só funciona no servidor, mas na maquina local, não envia mais:
Alguém ja passou por isso?

```
Transport.send(message);
```

Comment: Verifique proxy e firewall

Comment: o interessante que enviava. Aqui não uso proxy

Comment: que exceção adiciono para o firewall?

Comment: Qual o erro que você está tendo?

Comment: Não tem erro. Quando chega nessa linha do Transport.send(message) ele pára. Não acontece mais nada

Comment: experimentou desabilitar o IPV6, ex: 
```-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true```

Comment: não. Esse código eu implemento onde?

Comment: eu coloquei um debug e ele mostra isso:
    
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL false

Comment: pelo que está parecendo, parece ser o antivírus que está bloqueando. Mas ainda estou tentando descobrir como liberar no antivírus

Answer (score 0):

Consegui!

Era o antivírus que estava não estava permitindo o envio:
Fui no antivírus e desabilitei somente a função smtp e finalmente voltou a enviar novamente.
Tive essa ideia ao ver esse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907229/transport-sendmessage-not-working-in-the-below-code-netbeans-gets-stuck-at-t)

Obrigado!